# data.table does not allow lubridate's fast_strptime

Tags: r, data.table, lubridate

Say I have this `df`

```
df <- data.table(a = c('2022-01-20', '2022-01-21')
                 ); df
            a
1: 2022-01-20
2: 2022-01-21
```

Note that `lubridate` is able to convert this character column to date properly

```
fast_strptime(df$a, "%Y-%m-%d")

[1] "2022-01-20 UTC" "2022-01-21 UTC"
```

but when trying to store back to df `data.table` gives

```
df[, a := fast_strptime(a, "%Y-%m-%d") ]

Error in `[.data.table`(df, , `:=`(a, fast_strptime(a, "%Y-%m-%d"))) : 
      Supplied 9 items to be assigned to 2 items of column 'a'. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() to make this intent clear to readers of your code.
```

Looking forward to any ideas. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`strptime` returns a `list` with `POSIXlt` class

```
str(fast_strptime(df$a, "%Y-%m-%d"))
 POSIXlt[1:2], format: "2022-01-20" "2022-01-21"
> unclass(fast_strptime(df$a, "%Y-%m-%d"))
$sec
[1] 0 0

$min
[1] 0 0

$hour
[1] 0 0

$mday
[1] 20 21

$mon
[1] 0 0

$year
[1] 122 122

$wday
[1] NA NA

$yday
[1] NA NA

$isdst
[1] -1

attr(,"tzone")
[1] "UTC"
```

we may need to convert to `POSIXct`

```
df[, a := as.POSIXct(fast_strptime(a, "%Y-%m-%d")) ]
```

-output

```
> df
            a
       <POSc>
1: 2022-01-20
2: 2022-01-21
```

---

Instead of converting to `POSIXlt` and then to `POSIXct`, we could directly convert to `POSIXct` with a faster option `?parse_date_time2`

> parse_date_time2() is a fast C parser of numeric orders.

> fast_strptime() is a fast C parser of numeric formats only that accepts explicit format arguments, just like base::strptime().

```
df[, a := parse_date_time2(a, "%Y-%m-%d") ]
```

-output

```
> df
            a
       <POSc>
1: 2022-01-20
2: 2022-01-21
```

Comment: I tried `class(fast_strptime(df$a, "%Y-%m-%d"))` and it returned `"POSIXlt" "POSIXt"` which didn't answer what I wanted to find out e.g. vector, list. Thank you for the `unclass`.

Even more so with the `parse_date_time2` option. Speed is always good.

Comment: @SweepyDodo i meant that new attributes are added on top of the POSIXct class.  Just like your `df` object` `class(df)#
[1] "data.table" "data.frame"` is a data.frame as well as a data.table.  Most of the methods that work with data.frame works and it also adds some more methods for data.table.  Some may not work because the new class may have altered some